# How to replace default date (e.g. 0/1/1900) with blank using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub Macro9()
    Range("Table57[Weld Done]").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="0/1/1900", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=True, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Range("Table57[[#Headers],[Weld Done]]").Select
End Sub
```

I used the Replace function to replace default date 0/1/1900 with "blank" & it worked. So I recorded the workflow using VBA macro recording function & it gives coding as above.

When I try to use the macro, the value remains as default date 0/1/1900.

[image: Replace default date 0/1/1900 with "blank"]

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

Just change `"0/1/1900"` to `0` will do.

Comment: `"0/1/1900"` **is** `0`. The value zero will show as `"0/1/1900"` if formatted as date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the number `0` formatted as date is `0/1/1900`

I assume that they are the result of a calculation (you use a formula in those cells).
You can change the `.NumberFormat` of your range to something like:

```
[=0]"";D/M/YYYY
```

and this will hide the zero dates and show the cells as blanks.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. He asked how to use VBA to replace "0/1/1900" with "". Your answer does not attempt to deal with this.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Since the values obviously come from a formula because nobody would enter a date like `0/1/1900` and the formula autodeploys over the listobject (formatted as table) it does not make sense to remove those as they won't update anymore when data changes. • So obviously the OP run into an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where he asked the wrong question based on a wrong assumption. That's why my answer has a different solution.